# One true Lookup table advantages vs. disadvantages

Tags: database, database-design

So I've read enough to know that having one lookup table isn't the best way to go.  From a performance standpoint, why is that?  Consider the following example:

you have a list of schools in cities.  There can me more than one school in a given city.
So you have a junction table schoolCities between the two.  Now consider a list of businesses.  there can be more than one business in each city.  So you have a junction table businessCities.  The question really is: why is it so bad if you just use one cities table and make a junction table for schools and business versus having each table school and business its own copy of the cities table?

Comment: see http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're describing isn't the "one true lookup table;"  a Cities table in your example sounds like a good normalizing idea.  The "one true lookup table" would be more like

```
CREATE TABLE TheOne (
    LookupType varchar(20) NOT NULL -- City, color, shoe size...?
    , LookupValue varchar(1000) NOT NULL -- how big does it have to be?
    , CONSTRAINT pk_TheOne PRIMARY KEY (LookupType, LookupValue)
)
```

and you might have values:

```
'City', 'Philadelphia'
'City', 'St. Petersburg'
'City', 'Paris'
'State', 'Pennsylvania'
'State', 'Florida'
'Country', 'United States'
'Country', 'France'
'Brand', 'Lucky'
'Brand', 'Diesel'
'Brand', 'Old Navy'
```

and so on.  Pure evil.

A Cities table would probably associate a city with a State or other parent geographical region, since there can be many different cities with the same name (Paris, Lima, Levittown, etc).

Comment: can you give me a description of a one true lookup table?

Comment: http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html

Comment: You should have a primary key auto generated bigint or guid which is auto for all values. Then you would extend the table to have int1, int2, int3 etc. In the context of City, int1 is the pkId of the State which would reference the same table and resolve to the auto generated bigint/guid. In the contect of state, int1 is the pkId of the Country which would reference the same table and resolve to the auto generated bigint/guid ...and so on. I think this can work

Answer (score 16):

Actually, there can be some advantages to OTLT design (I literally feel heads exploding right now).

The model that I've seen work really well would be something like this.

LookupId, LookupTypeId, LanguageId, Description (the displayed data)

Then your params in the stored proc. would be just the typeid (to get all that type). If you just needed to transform the Id of a particular type, you'd just pass the LookupId. The default language would be set (in our case, it was English). This was a great way to skin the site's display data in a multi-language format.

We actually used it a Match.com and supported several million users per day on it very well. We literally just cached the lookups at web startup. It was a very efficient system. The biggest advantage was that we could literally just push data to production instead of big table schema additions / changes.

The way I look at it, as long as you're only dealing with small drop down data, etc. (typical application display stuff), it can offer big advantages in terms of performance, maintenance and ease of adding on new types.

I know it's an unpopular methodology.. However, it does work well in the right scenarios and if your use of it is limited AND disciplined.

Just my 2 cents. I'm sure I'll have points deducted or whatever for taking an unpopular stand on the topic though.

Comment: I completely agree. In certain circumstances wheres there's no inter-dependencies and its just a "dumb list" of values I don't see much of a downside compared to the efficiency advantages.

Comment: I am actually trying this model out using ASP.Net MVC. The problem is that I have too many controllers and views for just pure CRUD data. I would rather stash them all in one table and have a context to differentiate. If a context type grows and becomes coupled with complex business logic in the code then it can (and should) easily be exported into its own table with its own controller and views. But for the 20 other contexts that are really just categorised items...

Comment: This sounds more like a language table. I've used something like this before, but it also had a year column too as it was for performance reviews so it allowed us to keep a history of exactly what the review looked like each year. I have no problem with this pattern for that purpose for display items. I don't like using it for internal types as such. Like I wouldn't want replace all your xxxType tables with this pattern. One thing I hate about doing that is that looking at dependencies either in SQL or in code becomes virtually worthless.

Comment: agreed. internal types should be enums and such.. OTL is definitely better for public facing items such as select lists, text blurbs, etc..