# Refactor schema with multiple many-to-many relationships to semantically different but structurally similar entities?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, schema

I have a schema with a number of many to many relationships and what I'm seeing is a alot of similar data structure spread out among tables with different names.  The intuition I have is that there is a more efficient/desirable way to achieve the same result but I'm not sure what alternative approaches fall into reasonable design/best practices.

Note: Counries, TrafficTypes and People - as they exist now - could all be represented by Id and Name columns, but in the future may have additional fields.  Maybe what I'm after is some kind of technique akin to inheritance?

Here's the diagram of what I've got:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Don't lump together things which you think are similar; they may diverge later when you need to store more information about each entity.

Is there a problem with the number of tables you have in your database?

You are probably thinking about the problem from an object oriented design position and thinking you can use some sort of "parent" table to represent the common parts - databases don't work that way.

If you are not careful you will end up with a [MUCK](http://rodgersnotes.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/muck-massively-unified-code-key-generic-three-table-data-model/) or [OTLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380765/one-true-lookup-table-advantages-vs-disadvantages) table.

Answer (score 2):

Off the bat, I would keep seperate enties/objects/(cars vs animals) in seperate tables.

The chances of such enties overlapping properties are slim at best.

Thing is, once those entites start to evolve in your system, you will find that a single table will have hundreds of columns with singles populated per entity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how inheritance applies to your case.  But if you are interested in inheritance, as it applies to SQL tables or relations,  here are some things to look up:

At the level of ER modeling look up "ER model specialization".  This is the way the extended ER model diagrams "is A" relationships.

At the level of table design, look up "Class Table Inheritance" and "Shared primary key" for a couple of techniques that, used together, sort of mimic what inheritance does for you in an OOP.  You might also want to look up "single table inheritance" for an alternative that's simpler, but can be more wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. You're doing it right.

In a highly normalized schema, you're going to have tons of tables that are nearly identical.

As the others have said, what you're starting to consider (a generic table for multiple things) is a very bad idea and has many drawbacks.

The biggest drawback is that your relationships are made useless by it, in terms of maintaining data integrity. There's nothing stopping someone from assigning a CountryCode where a TrafficTypeId should be, and so on.

Another drawback would be that having one larger table will likely perform worse than many smaller, specialized tables; due to extra, unnecessary blocking.

Your may still want to implement some type of inheritance concept, but that'll be best done in whatever code accesses the database.