In EF Core 8, can a foreign key be assigned an additional constraint to a subset of the foreign key table?
I have a set of tables that contain what I am calling reference lists. In effect the tables contain a collection of enums, but I want them to be stored in the database rather that in code so I can use the values in apps that are not using EF - like a reporting tool, etc...
Simplified structure:
Table RefType:
  int RefTypeId PK
  string Code
  string Description

Table RefItem:
  int RefItemId PK
  int RefTypeId FK
  string Code
  string Description

RefType table example data:
RefTypeId     Code             Description
--------------------------------------------------------
1             'FILESTATUS'     'Status of the file'
2             'RECORDSTATUS'   'Status of the record'

RefItem table example data:
RefItemId    RefTypeId   Code         Description
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            1           'READY'      'The file is ready to be processed'
2            1           'PROCESSED'  'The file has been processed'
3            2           'READY'      'The record is ready to be processed'
4            2           'PROCESSED'  'The record has been processed'
5            1           'ERROR'      'The file has an error'
6            2           'FAILED'     'The record has failed processing'

My question: is it possible in EF Core 8 to create a foreign key relationship that references the RefItem.RefItemId column, but is additionally constrained to a subset of keys that belong to a specific RefType?
For example, in a table that stores the details of files I would want to have a foreign key to the RefItem table, RefItemId column, but only where the RefItem.RefTypeId == 1.
Likewise in a table storing the details of records the foreign key to the RefItem table, RefItemId column, should be constrained to RefItem.RefTypeId == 2.
Thanks!
P.

No, you cannot do this. Besides - while it might look like a smart idea to have a single table for all lookup values - it's really an anti-pattern. Check out this Ten Common Database Design Mistakes article - it's #5 on that list ("One table to hold all domain values"). Don't do this - each type of reference value needs to have its own table, so you can benefit from foreign key relationships

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573837/one-lookup-table-or-many-lookup-tables and Lookup Tables in SQL where Joe Celko says: "The One True look-up Table (OTLT) is a nightmare that keeps showing up" - don't do that - really not a good idea !

FYI in a table-per-heirachy, a child class can have a navigation property. And EF Core will apply the discriminator as a filter in any join query. But enum's are better, and you can use value conversions to store their names instead of their integer values for other query tools.

Hey @marc_s, thanks for the feedback, I wil take it on-board in my new project,. I have based this design on another set of tables that was created using db first. That databse has foreign key relationships on each column and an additional sql constraint that uses a scalar function to limit the allowable foreign key to the subset. This would seem to mitigate the first warning from the article in that it is easy to setup and maintain.....

... The biggest issue in that project is that EF is not "aware" of the contraint. Is there any work around for that? Additionally creating a separate table for each type would add 169 tables to that project, is that the recommended course? Finally, can the classes for these tables inherit a base class in EF?

Nope, this is a terrible idea, as per the reasons outlined in the comments. If you are using static compile-time value enumerations and want referential integrity (Lookup table) then define a table per Enum with a non-indenty PK and a comment with your enumeration to specify that any changes to this enumeration need to be reflected in the associated table. For instance:
public enum FileStatusIds
{
    None = 0,
    Ready = 1,
    Processed = 2,
    Error = 3
}

... With a matching table. I recommend explicit values for the enumerations and avoiding identity columns, to avoid any assumptions about what values match up to what where you could get deviations between environments.
I will usually also have an Entity declared for these tables, where the PK is typed as the enumeration where the DB column is an integer. For entities that would have a FileStatus I will almost always forgo the entity relationship and just expose the FileStatusId.
public class FileStatus
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerated.None)]
    public FileStatusId FileStatusId { get; protected set; }
    public string Name {get; protected set; }
    public string? Description { get; protected set; }
}

For instance if I have a SavedFile entity with a file status:
public FileStatusId FileStatusId { get; set; }

I wouldn't bother with a FileStatus navigation property. If I did possibly want something like the pretty name or description etc. I would pre-cache loading all FileStatus entities into global state so I could always do something like this when I might need it:
string description = GlobalState.FileStatuses.First(x => x.FileStatusId == fileStatusId).Description;

... where GlobalState.FileStatuses is a cache of DTOs representing the static state matching the enumeration. (Read once)  For pretty names I'm usually content to use a custom attribute on my enumeration where I have an extension method that can return it.
In case that option interests you:
public enum FileStatusIds
{
    None = 0,
    Ready = 1,
    Processed = 2,
    Error = 3,
    [Description("Not Available")]
    NotAvailable = 4
}

Static Extension Method:
/// <summary>
/// Helper method for resolving Description attributes.
/// </summary>
public static string Description(this Enum? value)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(value, nameof(value));

    FieldInfo? fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    if (fieldInfo == null)
        return value.ToString();

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
}

then using it in bindings and the like as @Model.FileStatusId.Description() etc.
It's not as customizable as putting a pretty name in the lookup table, requiring a re-deploy to change, but really, how often do static lookups like that actually change? :)

Here is some advice for your question and you could have a look.
1.EF cannot recognize the constraints in your database, but you can add constraints manually in code.
Method 1: Use Check constraints
Reference examples
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
.Entity<Product>()
        .ToTable(b => b.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Prices", "[Price] > [DiscountedPrice]"));
}

Reference DocumentationIndexes - EF Core | Microsoft Learn
Method 2: Use [RegularExpression(" ")]
Reference examples
public class Blog
{
    [RegularExpression("^A")]
    public string StartsWithA { get; set; }
}

Reference Documentation GitHub
2.Creating 169 sub-tables with RefType and RefItem will generate redundancy, which will improve query speed and data security to a certain extent, but will also increase data maintenance costs and storage space.
Whether to create 169 sub-tables or create views in existing tables depends on your needs.
3.The classes of these tables can inherit the base class in EF

But foreign keys don't work on views, so you are still breaking referential integrity on the database side.

@Phillip Jones, do you have time to check if my answer is helpful for you?
