# How to replace value by label from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some tables containing useful information but coded by numeric and one table containing the mapping between the numeric code and the label. The following are the examples:

Customer:

```
 id* | name | gender | group
----------------------------
   1 | M.T. |      0 |     1 
   2 | H.F. |      0 |     2 
   3 | Y.Y. |      1 |     1
```

Item:

```
 iid* | id | item
------------------
   1  |  1 |  123
   2  |  2 |  456
   3  |  2 |  789
```

Label:

```
 key* |    table | column | value |     label
----------------------------------------------
   1  | Customer | gender |     0 |         M
   2  | Customer | gender |     1 |         F
   3  | Customer |  group |     1 |      Gold
   4  | Customer |  group |     2 |    Sliver
   5  | Customer |  group |     3 |    Bronze
   6  |     Item |   item |   123 | Product A
   7  |     Item |   item |   124 | Product B
   8  |     Item |   item |   456 |  Item 456
   9  |     Item |   item |   789 |    Book Y
  10  |     Item |   item |   790 |    Book Z
```

I would like to generate the results of queries on Customer and Item as below.

Customer:

```
 id | name | gender |  group
-----------------------------
  1 | M.T. |      M |   Gold 
  2 | H.F. |      M | Sliver 
  3 | Y.Y. |      F |   Gold
```

Item:

```
 iid | id |      item
----------------------
  1  |  1 | Product A
  2  |  2 |  Item 456
  3  |  2 |    Book Y
```

The below are the SQL I wrote to generate the results.

For querying Customer:

```
select
  c.id,
  c.name,
  l1.label as gender,
  l2.label as group
from Customer c
left join Label l1 
  on l1.table = 'Customer' and l1.column = 'gender' and c.gender = l1.value
left join Label l2 
  on l2.table = 'Customer' and l2.column = 'group' and c.group = l2.value
```

For querying Item:

```
select
  i.iid,
  i.id,
  l1.label as item
from Item i
left join Label l1
  on l1.table = 'Item' and l1.column = 'item' and l1.value = i.item
```

Is there any better SQL to do such things?

How can I use the values in *table* and *column* in Label table so that I don't need to hardcode the table name and column name to map the label?

If there are many columns to be mapped by labels, my SQL require many LEFT JOIN clauses. Is this avoidable?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? If you don't want one, then you should not add the PL/SQL tag.

Comment: This is the anti-pattern known [**One True Lookup Table**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380765/one-true-lookup-table-advantages-vs-disadvantages). Good luck with it...

Comment: O... we are editing concurrently. I deleted the tag.

Comment: Just to add a link to something I wrote 12 years ago(!) [Oracle-WTF: The Concrete Elephant Approach](http://oracle-wtf.blogspot.co.uk/2006/02/eav-returns-concrete-elephant-approach.html)

Comment: I'm not the one who created the database...

Comment: *"I'm not the one who created the database..."* As is so often the case, the person who builds a shonky data model is not the person who has to work with it. So you have our commiserations, but the problems you are experiencing are why this model is widely regarded as an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there are many columns to be mapped by labels, my SQL require many
>   LEFT JOIN clauses. Is this avoidable?

This data model is somewhat suspicious, but if you have to deal with it you can avoid multiple left joins using `pivot` or `case when`:

**<sup>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/360)</sup>**

```
select c.id, c.name, 
       max(case when col = 'gender' then label end) gender,
       max(case when col = 'group'  then label end) grp
  from customer c
  left join label l 
    on l.tbl = 'Customer' and (l.col, l.value) in (('gender', c.gender), ('group', c.grp))
  group by c.id, c.name
```

Try to avoid naming columns as "table", "column", "group", they are [reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle.