# Is OTLT (One True Lookup Table) ever a good approach?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Whenever I see OTLT (One True Lookup Table), aka MUCK (Massively Unified Code-Key), pattern mentioned anywhere, it is described as [pure evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380765/one-true-lookup-table-advantages-vs-disadvantages#answer-9381184:%7E:text=Pure%20evil.) and [one of the worst design mistakes you can make](https://rodgersnotes.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/muck-massively-unified-code-key-generic-three-table-data-model/#PDRTJS_3451668_post_191_msg:%7E:text=one%20of%20the%20worst%20DB%20design%20mistakes%20you%20can%20make.). However, I'm currently working on a project where this pattern is used and seems appropriate. Below is the table structure (slightly simplified):

```
create table LOOKUP_TYPE
(
    CODE         nvarchar(20) PK,
)

create table LOOKUP_VALUE
(
    ID           int PK identity,
    TYPE_CODE    nvarchar(20) references LOOKUP_TYPE(CODE),
    VALUE        nvarchar(255)
)
```

These tables contain *hundreds* of types. Additionally, there two "supporting" tables: `LOOKUP_VALUE_TRANS`, which holds translations, and `INTEGRATION_VALUE`, which provides mapping between 3rd party and internal types & values. `LOOKUP_VALUE_TRANS` and `INTEGRATION_VALUE` each have similar number of records to base tables.

A "solution" to OTLT that I've seen suggested would be to store each `LOOKUP_TYPE` in it's own table. In this case, that would require 3 tables per single `LOOKUP_TYPE` record, which will more than double the number of tables in the database and, in turn, massively bloat data access code / configuration of the application.

**Is that really practical? Should I be placing this much value on database's ability to universally enforce referential integrity?**

**Is there an alternative that helps maintain referential integrity without creating huge number of tables?**

Comment: As long as OLT works for your application, sure, use it.  I'm 64, and I remember when referential integrity was something you had to code in your application because no database or file system supported such a thing.

Comment: "massively bloat data access code" is what you get from Unifying the Code-Key. That is, unless every `VALUE` is genuinely a `nvarchar(255)`. Suppose some of your `VALUE`s are actually `int` or `Bool` or `Date/Time` or fixed-length `char`: then everything that accesses them spends its time converting from/to `nvarchar(255)`; say you want to compare two `date`s, or calculate the difference between two `int`s; you can't use native SQL arithmetic or comparisons to do that in your query. Instead you must write bloated code to do half the job in SQL, half in application code.

Comment: "double the number of tables in the database" is almost certainly a Good Thing; and I would expect a factor much more than double. At least have a distinct `LOOKUP_VALUE` table for each distinct `VALUE` type.

Comment: As @GilbertLeBlanc says, I can remember when some people thought MUCK 'saved' tables. That was the 1980's when they were also using 2-digit years to 'save' disk.

Comment: "huge number of tables" what do you think is the 'right' number of tables, and why? ERPs typically have thousands of base tables, and tens of thousands of views or derived tables -- and some simplistic ERPs try to reduce that by mashing together disparate tables which have a vaguely similar structure, and end up with a bazillion nulls because as the application gets more complex, the tables get more disparate. Suggest you go get some foundation knowledge on database normalisation and data integrity and avoiding update anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics365 is using this pattern (StringMap). I think it is okay as many commerical successful softwares are using this pattern.